# Sparql query for wgs84 rdf

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have this RDF file and i like to make query to select the individual mark, but i can't. please can some one help me

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
     xml:base="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> 

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/ont.owl#mark">
        <lat rdf:datatype="&xsd;double">121231.0</lat>
        <alt rdf:datatype="&xsd;double">2131.0</alt>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Comment: you want to select this specific mark depending on the coordinate? Did you try some query?

Comment: yes, select ?x where { ?x :lat "121231.0" }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value you are trying to select has a datatype so you must include that in your query i.e.

```
PREFIX : <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?x
WHERE
{
  ?x :lat "121231.0"^^xsd:double
}
```

Otherwise the terms do not match and nothing will be selected

Comment: @user205512 That would be interpreted as a decimal rather than a double per the SPARQL specification so that wouldn't work.  A plain literal needs the exponent to be present to be treated as a double

Comment: Sigh, one day I'll learn to read. `?x :lat ?lat . filter (?lat = 121231)` will work.

Comment: @user205512 Yes that will work but be much slower than selecting a specific value depending on the size of the database.  It's a linear scan vs an index lookup